# Warum heißt es »mein Lebtag« und nicht »meinen Lebtag«?

Tags: idiomaticity, possessive-pronoun, collocation

**Beschreibung und Beispiele**

Der Ausdruck **Lebtag** wird in der Redewendung »mein / dein / ihr… Lebtag [nicht]« verwendet, um auszudrücken, dass etwas das ganze Leben lang oder bisher noch nie der Fall war.
Üblicherweise wird das Possessivpronomen dabei nicht gebeugt:

> Sie hat **ihr** Lebtag keine Kopfschmerzen gehabt.
>   Ich habe **mein** Lebtag gern gearbeitet.

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lebtag) nennt allein die ungebeugte Form (Hervorh. von mir):

> [all] mein, dein usw. Lebtag (umgangssprachlich: das ganze Leben lang, solange ich lebe/du lebst usw.: all **ihr** Lebtag hatte sie gearbeitet; daran wirst du **dein** Lebtag denken!)

Auch bei Wiktionary entsprechen die Beispiele diesem Muster (Hervorh. von mir):

> Bedeutungen:
>   veraltend, nur in Wendungen: Zeit, die jemand lebt, bzw. (noch) gelebt hat
>
> Beispiele:
>   **Mein** Lebtag habe ich das noch nicht erlebt.
>   Das hat er **sein** Lebtag lang gesucht.

Auch im [Wörterbuch der deutschen Gegenwartssprache](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wdg/Lebtag) finden sich ausschließlich Beispiele mit dieser Verwendung.

Das [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Lebtag) bestätigt dies in der eigenen Grammatik- und Beispielsektion, doch unter den dort zusammengetragenen Verwendungsbeispielen finden sich auch gebeugte Possessivpronomen (Hervorh. von mir):

> Jetzt bin ich schon wieder ein paar Jahre älter und immer genau gleich mager wie ich **meiner** Lebtag immer gewesen bin. (*Späth, Gerold: Commedia, Frankfurt a. M.: S. Fischer 1980 [1980], S. 21*)
>
> Sie erlebte gestern eine Testfahrt, die sie **ihren** Lebtag nicht vergessen wird. (*Bild, 21.03.2001*)

---

Die Definitionen und Beispiele der genannten Wörterbücher sind sich also einig, dass das Possessivpronomen in diesem Fall nicht gebeugt wird, wohingegen die den Medien entnommenen Beispiele im DWDS eine nicht ganz so strenge Verwendung nahelegen.

Im [Grimm’schen Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL03077#XGL03077) findet sich schließlich ein Hinweis, aber keine Erklärung (Hervorh. im Original):

> 3) *am häufigsten, und heute in der schriftsprache noch einzig, in festen zeitlichen formeln, accusativen und genitiven.*
>   a) *der acc. des singulars in:*
>   der seinen lebtag nichts gethan.
>   Weckherlin 813;
>
> *ungewis, ob der des sing. oder des plur. in der gewöhnlichen formel* mein lebtag, *die aus* meinen lebtag *oder aus* meine lebtage *gekürzt sein kann, ebenso* dein, sein lebtag: all mein läbtag, alle zeit meines läbens. Maaler 260a;

Dass es sich um eine feste Formel handelt, mag zwar korrekt sein, erklärt aber nicht, warum dies so ist.
Zugleich wird vermutet, es handle sich um eine Verkürzung aus der gebeugten Form, doch ohne dies zu belegen.

**Wieso wird das Possessivpronomen in *mein Lebtag* nicht (oder nur selten) gebeugt?
Um was für eine Konstruktion handelt es sich in linguistischer Hinsicht?**

Comment: Hmmm. Das klingt sehr"altertümlich" für mich.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Für mich nicht, aber eher schriftsprachlich. Man findet auch beide Varianten. Der Duden kennt aber nur die (mutmaßlich) nicht der Grammatik entsprechende Form.

Comment: Die Frage nach dem "warum" ist trotzdem etwas seltsam. Was genau erwartest Du als Antwort darauf? Belege für die Korrektheit, bzw. Inkorrektheit, hast Du ja offensichtlich bereits gefunden.

Comment: Eine Erklärung, die ich verstehen kann und die über "Das ist halt so" hinausgeht. Der Ausdruck ist auf diese Art gebräuchlich, widerspricht aber dem, was ich (abgesehen davon, dass ich ihn  so kenne) erwarten würde.

Comment: Eine Erklärung, warum der Ausdruck von der grammatischen Norm abweicht.

Comment: Füge doch bitte die bisher gefundenen Erklärungen und Zitate Deine Frage hinzu.

Comment: Gern, ich mache es morgen, wenn ich am PC bin - mit meinem Handy ist das mühsam.

Comment: Wenn Du schon bei DWDS warst, was stellt Dich an der Antwort "in der schriftsprache [nur] in festen zeitlichen formeln (vorkommend)" nicht zufrieden?

Comment: Ich kenne den Ausdruck aus der Mundart meiner Eltern eher mit Genitiv: "Ich hab meiner Lebtag immer hart gearbeitet".

Comment: Die selbe Frage stellt sich offenbar  auch die BILD: „Sie erlebte gestern eine Testfahrt, die sie ihren Lebtag nicht vergessen wird.“
Bild, 21.03.2001. Gefunden auf: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Lebtag

Comment: Es gibt Dialekte (zumindest außerhalb Süddt.), in denen klingt meinen wie mein’n. Vielleicht haben sie hier eine Rolle gespielt und zur Verkürzung geführt? Dazu wäre zunächst zu prüfen, ob in diesen Dialekten die Wendung auftrat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul, Wiehl & Grosse gehen in ihrer *Mittelhochdeutsche Grammatik* an verschiedenen Stellen auf Synkopen und Apokopen ein. Über den unbestimmten Artikel und die Possessivpronomina schreiben sie in § 53 e), dass diese satzunbetont das /ə/ der Endungssilbe einbüßen **konnten.** Als Beispiele führen sie an: statt *eines, einem, einen, eineʒ* konnte *eins, eim, ein, einʒ* stehen; statt *mînes, dînem, sînen* konnte stehen: *mîns, dîm, sîn.* Analog also auch *mîn* statt *mînen.*

In § 53 e) Anm. 3 b) weisen sie darauf hin, dass insbesondere Liquide und Nasale den Ausfall begünstigen. Als Beispiel nennen sie Akk. Sg. *kein(en)*. Analog also: *mein(en)*. Das Phänomen, dass bei *keinØn; meinØn* zwei identische Phoneme in Lautung und Schreibung verschmelzen, übergehen sie an dieser Stelle stillschweigend.

Damit sind die Fragen nach dem **Woher?** und dem **Seit wann?** vermutlich erschöpfend beantwortet. Die Frage, **warum** Sprecher / Schreiber es vor Jahrhunderten so gemacht haben und es auch heute noch tun in Sätzen wie „Ich ruf’ mein’ Bruder an.“, beantworte ich mit einem einzigen Wort: Sprachökonomie.

Allerdings ist auch multiplex’ Vermutung einer Kontamination nicht ohne. Ob aber nun das eine oder das andere oder beides oder ein drittes: Es läuft wohl auf die in der wissenschaftlichen Literatur gängige Wendung hinaus: „… lässt sich nicht [mehr] ermitteln.“

Answer (score 3):

Vermutlich hat sich die Form **mein Lebtag** als umgangssprachliche oder dialektische Verkürzung gebildet.

Die Form **meinen Lebtag** wäre, meinem Sprachverständnis nach, korrekt und ich bin auch schon Personen begegnet, die diese Form nutzen. (Möglicherweise ist die genutzte Formulierung vom jeweiligen Dialekt abhängig?)

Da die Formulierung schon recht alt ist, kann es durchaus auch sein, dass der Apostroph, der bei einer umgangssprachlichen Verkürzung nötig wäre, (**mein' Lebtag**) einfach verloren gegangen ist. Damit ist es natürlich einfach, dies als ungebeugte Form zu interpretieren und entsprechende Regeln anzuwenden.

Da sich die Sprechenden selten Gedanken über Konstruktionsdetails ihrere Sprache machen solange sie verstanden werden, können sich solche Regelabweichungen über die Zeit sehr einfach als Standart etablieren.

Answer (score 3):

Hier geht es ja nicht um einen LebTAG, sondern um ein LEBtag, ein Leben. Ein ganzes (bisheriges) Leben und nicht um einen bestimmten Tag.- Vielleicht sollte mit dieser Bezeichnung deutlich gemacht werden, dass das Leben eines Menschen nur ein Tag in der Ewigkeit ist...
Ich hab auch mal gelesen, dass "Leben" ursprünglich "lebetac" hieß.

Comment: Das "gelesen" scheint richtig zu sein. Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lebtag) gibt beispielsweise als Herkunft "mittelhochdeutsch lebetac = Lebenszeit" an.

Answer (score 2):

Wie IQV kommentierte:

> Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lebtag) gibt beispielsweise als Herkunft "mittelhochdeutsch lebetac = Lebenszeit" an.

Mit Bezug auf IQVs Hinweis: Das sagt ja auch Lexer. Nur war auch schon mhd. *lëbetac* masc. Die Herkunft als solche hilft also nicht weiter. Da *lëbetac* aber *(das) Leben* bedeutete, und auch bereits mhd. *lëben* n. war, vermute ich eine Kontamination.

Comment: Kommentare können später mal leicht gelöscht werden, weswegen es ungünstig ist, eine Antwort ganz wesentlich auf einen Kommentar zu stützen, ohne dessen Inhalt zu wiederholen. Überhaupt scheint mir dies hier eher eine Antwort auf einen Kommentar zu sein, als auf die eigentliche Frage.

Answer (score 0):

Ich kann leider nur etwas zur grammatischen Einordnung im Satzverbund sagen, warum allerdings gerade hier die Beugung nicht vollführt wird, habe ich auch noch nicht gefunden.

**ihr Lebtag (lang)** und **mein Lebtag gern** sind Adverbiale der Zeit (Temporaladverbiale). Adverbiale beschreiben die Tätigkeit näher und können mit Präpositionen oder nicht versehen sein. Ohne Präposition ist die Fallbestimmung leider schwerer. Man kann aber fragen: Für wie lange hat sie keine Kopfschmerzen gehabt? Die Präposition "für" steht hier für eine Dauer und erfordert damit den Akkusativ. Auch das Possessivpronom muss nun in Abhängigkeit der Bestimmung richtig dekliniert werden.
Darum empfinde ich die Form "ihren Lebtag" besser geeignet.

Beispiele für Adverbiale mit Präposition, hier Lokaladverbiale:

> Das Bild hängt an meiner Wand.
>   Ich gehe zu meinem Bäcker.

Weiteres Beispiel für ein Adbverbial ohne Präposition (Akkusativ):

> Ich gehe den ganzen Tag lang.